# Change Date Format

Tags: community, datetime, date

I have my date in following format...

> 2015-10-28 (YYYY-MM-dd)

... in Email Template. I want it in the following format:

> 28-Oct-2015 01:31 PM (dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm am/pm)

How can I get this format?

Currently my Code line is

```
(pi.TargetObjectId,pi.createdby.name+' on '+ pi.createddate.format('dd-MMM-YYYY '));
```

Comment: You're working with the CreatedDate? That's a DateTime field anyway?

Comment: following should work pi.createddate.format('dd-M-YYYY h:mm a')